# Postman post won't work, neither does curl to express server. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: express, postman

This is my express code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');

const app = express();

app.use(authRoutes);

const mongoUri = 'mongodb+srv://admin:qwer1234@cluster0-2sdoa.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useCreateIndex: true,
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
 console.log("connected to mongo instance");
}); // when we connect successfully, this callback is called

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
 console.log("Error on connection to mongo", err)
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.send('Hi there');
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log("listneing on port 3000")
});
```

and authRoutes is:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router(); // object to associate route handlers with it

router.post('signup', (req, res) => { //receieve post request to signup
  console.log("got here");
  res.send("made post request");
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I use postman to post to localhost:3000/signup, I get a `Cannot post /signup` in my body. When I curl I get:

```
curl localhost:3000
Hi there

curl --request POST localhost:3000/signup
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /signup</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the get works but the post does not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signup route is missing a forward slash.

This should resolve the issue:

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
```